# how to find particular color in an uiimage and change that color

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I want to find particular colour in an image,for example I have an image which has many colours.by assigning red parameter i want change other colour pixels except red colour pixels. please watch the below image. in the above updated image only blur colour is highlighted all other colours were changed.

[image]
Updated Pic

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW2 ? It seems as you'd need something like a reverse chroma-key filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I got curious on how hard would it be to achieve this reverse chroma-key, and it turns out that given the [example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW2) it is quite easy!

```
// Allocate memory
const unsigned int size = 32;
float *cubeData = (float *)malloc (size * size * size * sizeof (float) * 4);
float rgb[3], *c = cubeData;
CGFloat hue = CGFLOAT_MAX;

CGFloat minHueAngle = 210;
CGFloat maxHueAngle = 240;

// Populate cube with a simple gradient going from 0 to 1
for (int z = 0; z < size; z++){
    rgb[2] = ((double)z)/(size-1); // Blue value
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
        rgb[1] = ((double)y)/(size-1); // Green value
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x ++){
            rgb[0] = ((double)x)/(size-1); // Red value
            // Convert RGB to HSV
            // You can find publicly available rgbToHSV functions on the Internet
            UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:rgb[0] green:rgb[1] blue:rgb[2] alpha:1];
            [color getHue:&hue saturation:nil brightness:nil alpha:nil];
            hue *= 360;

            // Use the hue value to determine which to make transparent
            // The minimum and maximum hue angle depends on
            // the color you want to remove
            float alpha = (hue > minHueAngle && hue < maxHueAngle) ? 1.0f: 0.0f;
            // Calculate premultiplied alpha values for the cube
            c[0] = rgb[0] * alpha;
            c[1] = rgb[1] * alpha;
            c[2] = rgb[2] * alpha;
            c[3] = alpha;
            c += 4; // advance our pointer into memory for the next color value
        }
    }
}
// Create memory with the cube data
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cubeData
                                    length:(size * size * size * sizeof (float) * 4)
                              freeWhenDone:YES];
CIFilter *colorCube = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorCube"];
[colorCube setValue:@(size) forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
[colorCube setValue:data forKey:@"inputCubeData"];

UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage];
[colorCube setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];


UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[colorCube outputImage]];
```

This resulted in this image, from your example image :
[image]

I've got to say it looks pretty decent, given I only tinkered with the values for a minute or two. Of course, to achieve the total end result you want, you'd need to use two more filters - namely `CIPhotoEffectMono` and `CISourceOverCompositing` to first make your original image black & white and then overlay the result from CubeMap filter on the black & white image.

Comment: Have you had a look at the GPUImage library? https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2  You can find most image processing filters you need there

Comment: Thank you so much @Losiowaty It saved me a lot .I am new to IOS so could you please help me in finding the min and max Hue values of red,green,purple,yellow and cyan colours.

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with iOS ;) i got the value for blue (240) from Wikipedia and just experimented with min/max for a litttle until I got satisfactory results ;)

Comment: I am having an issue in this when I particularly mention a colour its working perfectly but when I give RGB colour it is not working perfectly. Could you please help me on this @Losiowaty

Comment: Well, it is bound to get trickier with arbitrary colors - you'd need to first extract their hue, saturation and brightness, use them as baselines and then compare each of this to the respective values extracted in the loop with some margins. There is no easy answer for this, at least not one I can think off. It may be a good idea to add sliders with which you'd control the min/max of hue/brightness/saturation and experiment with the results in realtime.